# Jquery auto complete, filtering some results out

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

While applying jQuery UI autocomplete to an input field, I need to filter several results out and not show them as a selectable, because I cannot control the autocomple results, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you using ajax to get results?  Do you want to SHOW the results but NOT have them selectable or just NOT SHOW them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my code for autocomplete adresses with google geocoder. just implement iLikeYou() and it should work

```
$("#myInput").autocomplete({
             source: function(request, response) {
                geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term}, function(results, status) {
                {
                    var res = Array();
                    for(i in results){
                        // filter here!!!
                        if (iLikeYou(){
                           res.push({
                              label:results[i].formatted_address,
                               value:results[i].formatted_address+'|'+results[i].geometry.location
                           });
                        }
                    }
                }

                response(res);
            });   

            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event,ui){
                // i make some nice actions
            }
    });
```